# Export to formatted PDF from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

I am very new to MS Access. The objective is to export multiple PDF files from MS Access DB. Currently I can export multiple Excel files through the following code. But I want to export it to PDF with few format changes in table (Colors, Font etc) and adding Header & Footer notes to the PDF.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
Dim rsGroup As DAO.Recordset
Dim ColumnName As String
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "E:\TestExport\"

Set rsGroup = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT TableName.Column FROM TableName", dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rsGroup.EOF
    ColumnName = rsGroup!Column

    Dim rsExportSQL As String
    rsExportSQL = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TableName.Column='" & ColumnName & "'"

    Dim rsExport As DAO.QueryDef
    Set rsExport = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQueryDef", rsExportSQL)


    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "myExportQueryDef", myPath & RegionName & ".xls", True

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete rsExport.Name

    rsGroup.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I would recommend creating a report based on that query of yours to finely adjust the details and formatting. Once the report is done just create a template out of it for any other queries, and vba export to pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, PDFs are structured, fixed formatted document files and not dynamic data files. Consider the following routine:

1. Pre-design a report using the full table (not any query) as a
   recordsource. Style it in any way (i.e., landscape/portrait, headers, fonts, colors) for final dissemination or presentation.
2. Using the [DoCmd.OpenReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx) method, open the report in Print Preview, conditionally changing report's filter by loop value using the *WhereCondition* argument of the method.
3. Then run [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) to output the previewed report to PDF format in same loop. NOTE: Full table is never outputted, only filtered records.

**VBA** Code

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
  Dim rsGroup As DAO.Recordset
  Dim ColumnName As String, myPath As String

  myPath = "E:\TestExport\"

  Set rsGroup = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Column FROM TableName", _
                                        dbOpenDynaset)        
  Do While Not rsGroup.EOF
     ColumnName = rsGroup!Column

     ' OPEN REPORT, FILTERING RECORDSOURCE BY COLUMN VALUE
     DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , "Column='" & ColumnName & "'"
     ' OUTPUT REPORT TO FILE
     DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, _
                                    myPath & ColumnName & ".pdf", False
     ' CLOSE PREVIEW
     DoCmd.Close acReport, "ReportName"

     rsGroup.MoveNext
  Loop

  rsGroup.Close
  Set rsGroup = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lybren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6435422/lybren)'s solution is the right approach to take. Create reports off all the queries you want to export and then, in VBA, use the [Docmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) method to export the reports as PDFs. Below is a code example:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MyReportToExport", acFormatPDF, "C:/Users/MyUserAccount/Documents/MyExportedPDF.pdf"
```

You could also just export the queries by changing "acOutputReport" to "acOutputQuery" but by using reports, you have a lot more control over formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I got the code to export PDF from a report in many forum. Actually I wanted to know a procedure/code in a single script to do all the things. In my given code you can see a query is randomly creating for loop and after completing the loop it was deleted. Simply is there any procedure/code where I can save the query as formatted report and export the report as PDF. I tried a lot but there is no luck. Can you help me a little? Thanks again