# How to make a query with one parameter that has multiple values?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make a query which will export a report for multiple clients.

Right now the way I have it set up is with multiple queries, each one for each client, but I would like to make a single query, because eventually I will run into hundreds of queries and reports, which could be done in just 1 query and 1 report.

What I would like is a query with a parameter, which would be [client], and when I execute the query, it would run for each client inside the [client] parameter. Obviously, each client would be "saved" in a different file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to formatted PDF from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038247/export-to-formatted-pdf-from-ms-access)

Comment: This requires VBA code. Open recordset object of clients and in a loop of recordset, open report using OpenReport WHERE argument to filter, export report, close report, repeat.